# Apache - Log access by executing php file

Tags: apache

i do redirect visitors of a webpage to another location.

But i also want to log these requests by sending the log data to a php file.

Is there a way to call a php file from .htaccess for example to log these requests ?

I do a RewriteRule to the new location.

Is there a way to call also a php file (the visitor should not be directed there) that will log the request ?

Should i define these settings in .htaccess ?

Thanks !

Comment: Should i do something like this : 

CustomLog "|/usr/bin/php /dolog/dolog.php?request_file=REQUEST_FILENAME"

or is there another way to call dolog.php ?